# Python Генератор Паролей

Tags: python, python-3.x, generate

Я пытаюсь написать генератор паролей, который включает в себя английский/русский алфавит, специальные символы, числа. С помощью чего (библиотеки или примеры кода) я могу реализовать последовательной перебор паролей?

Например, что-то вроде: AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD, AAE и так далее, только ещё учитывая спец.символы, числа.

Comment: так, все-таки, "генератор паролей" или "перебор паролей"? )) и добавьте в вопрос ваш код?

Comment: `itertools.combinations`, по-моему тут обсуждали не раз, в частности было обсуждение, как генерить строки, похожие на псевдонимы пользователей

Comment: @CrazyElf лучше `product`

Comment: @Jack_oS где можно сгенерировать, там можно и перебрать)

Comment: @Дмитрий генерируется случайная  комбинация а перебор это последовательное изменение значений и их проверка. Перебирать генератором можно но может случиться что он никогда не найдет пароль. И в любом случае (если звезды не сойдутся) займет больше времени

Comment: @Kers пошутить же пытался я)

Comment: @Дмитрий ну вот в коем веки поумничал и оказалось зря ))

Comment: @Kers, что показывает, что петросян из меня так себе(( а так хотелось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для перебор можно реализовать через itertools

```py
import itertools

alfavit = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] # и тд
pasw = "adcefb" # Искомый пароль
lenpas = 6 # Длинна пароля

for i in itertools.product(alfavit, repeat=lenpas):
    a = ''.join(i)
    if a == pasw:
        print(f"Пароль найден {a}")
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

это можно сделать с помощью `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools

for el in itertools.product("ABC", repeat=3):
    print("".join(el))
```

Вместо `ABC` можно поставить любое нужное вам значение